Injective resolution of $C^{\infty}_X$
Let X be a smooth real manifold. I'm looking for an injective resolution for the sheaf $C^{\infty}_X$ which is the sheaf where for any $U\subseteq X$ open, $C^{\infty}_X(U):=C^{\infty}(U)$. Does exist any explicit example of it?

This sheaf is a soft sheaf. For the purposes of sheaf cohomology that already tells you its higher compactly supported cohomologies vanish and if you use the "right" definition of manifold it also tells you the ordinary cohomologies vanish. What do you need an injective resolution for? I doubt an explicit one exists to be honest. The usual construction is quite abstract
